# mysql select count rows from a table where column like values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to better explain the title with an example

table 1 example

```
Id  text
1   lorem ipsum doe
2   foo bar lorem ipsum jhon
3   bla bla ipsum tommy
```

table 2 example

```
Id  fullname  name  surname  keyword
1   jhon doe  jhon  doe      jhon
2   tom asd   tom   asd      tom
3   sam frf   sam   frr      sam
```

expected table result using like or regexp?

```
fullname  count(*)
jhon doe  2
tom asd   1
sam frf   0
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some perf test with my real data

t1 => 100,000 rows and growing

t2 => 207 rows

test 1

```
SELECT 
    t2.fullname,
    count(t1.id) AS total
FROM
    table_1 AS t1
        RIGHT JOIN
    table_2 AS t2 ON t1.text REGEXP t2.keyword
GROUP BY t2.fullname
ORDER BY total DESC

212 seconds
```

test 2

```
SELECT 
    t2.fullname,
    count(t1.id) AS total
FROM
    table_1 AS t1
        RIGHT JOIN
    table_2 AS t2 ON t1.text LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.keyword, '%')
GROUP BY t2.fullname
ORDER BY total DESC

30 seconds
```

test 3

```
SELECT 
    t2.fullname,
    count(t1.id) AS total
FROM
    table_1 AS t1
        RIGHT JOIN
    table_2 AS t2 ON t1.text LIKE lower(CONCAT('%', t2.name, '%')) AND t1.text LIKE lower(CONCAT('%', t2.surname, '%'))
GROUP BY t2.fullname
ORDER BY total DESC

32 seconds
```

test 4

```
SELECT 
    t2.fullname,
    count(t1.id) AS total
FROM
    table_1 AS t1
        RIGHT JOIN
    table_2 AS t2 ON t1.text LIKE lower(CONCAT('%', t2.name, '%')) OR t1.text LIKE lower(CONCAT('%', t2.surname, '%'))
GROUP BY t2.fullname
ORDER BY total DESC

40 seconds
```

test 5

```
SELECT 
    t2.fullname,
    count(t1.id) as total
FROM
    table_1 as t1
        RIGHT JOIN
    table_2 as t2 ON t1.text LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.keyword, '%') OR (t1.text LIKE lower(CONCAT('%', t2.name, '%')) AND t1.text LIKE lower(CONCAT('%', t2.surname, '%')))
GROUP BY t2.fullname
ORDER BY total DESC

41 seconds
```

I'll pick test 5.
Best compromise results/perf

Any further advice?

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest was is to use REGEXP.

```
SELECT fullname, 
       Count(t1.id) 
FROM   table1 t1 
       RIGHT JOIN table2 t2 
               ON t1.text REGEXP t2.keyword 
GROUP  BY fullname
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d8cf/10)

I used an RIGHT join so that you'd get the Zero for sam (otherwise it would just be eliminated)

Comment: +1, good one (I'm not use to MySQL, so didn't know about `REGEXP`)

Comment: your query works as expected but I forgot an important thing and it's very slow. sorry! table 1 => 98.000 rows and growing  table 2 => 207 rows. Is there a way to achieve the same result in a quickest way? thanks again

Comment: If SELECT perf is important you could split out the string into another table and join to that. Otherwise I don't think there's anything that's going to be faster.

Comment: using REGEXP it takes 200 seconds to perform the query. while using LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.name, '%') it takes 30 seconds to achieve the same result. do you think we can do something better?

Comment: @fedefede0101 Honestly I'm impressed that CONCAT works as well as it does. You should probably add that as an answer so it can help others.

Comment: @Lamak apparently there is way to do the LIKE and the perf is better

Comment: I'm doing some perf test with my real data on different ways and I'm trying to get the most correct result even if I know that in this way I'll miss some occurences or get some wrong occurences. I'm ok with that! I'll edit soon my original post and add an answer. is it ok? sorry if I ask that but I'm pretty new as active user on stackoverflow :(

Comment: @fedefede0101 I'd say its better to add an answer rather than updating your question since it fits the Q&A format better. Although since you're below 100 rep you have to wait 7 hours. Here's [the Faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/148672) on meta that goes into length about this